# Comma separated Output in yii2

Tags: yii2

In the user table I have mobileno column for every user. And in the auth_assignment table I haveauthoriations. I want all mobile no of all the users who has autthoriation 'c_apo'. The output I want is only - `7777777777,9999999999`.

The query I'm using is -

```
$mobiletemp = User::find()->leftJoin('auth_assignment', 'auth_assignment.user_id = user.id')->select('mobileno')->andWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => 'c_apo'])->asArray()->all();
$mobile = ArrayHelper::getColumn($mobiletemp, 'mobileno');
var_dump($mobile);
```

The output I'm getting is -

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "9999999999" [1]=> string(10) "7777777777" } }
```

Comment: You can use php implode fuction. `$mobile = implode(",", $mobile);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mobile = User::find()
->select('mobileno')
->leftJoin('auth_assignment', 'auth_assignment.user_id = user.id')
->andWhere(['auth_assignment.item_name' => 'c_apo'])
->column();

$mobile = implode(",", $mobile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is a possible solution 

public $exitingMember;//have to declare virtual field in model

$alreadyMember = TaskCrewEmployee::find()
->select('GROUP_CONCAT(tce_u_id) as exitingMember')
->where(['tce_ts_id'=>500])
->groupBy(['tce_ts_id'])
->one();
```